# Adding markers to elevation service GMaps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the GMaps Code of the Google Developers for the GMaps Elevation Service. By clicking on the map it automatically opens an info window. Now I tried to integrate a marker object. My aim is to "freeze" markers on the map which carry the elevation information. However, step by step, first of all, by clicking on the map I see no markers. I would be very grateful for a hint. Thanx!

Here is the code:

```
 var elevator;
 var map;

var freiburg = new google.maps.LatLng(47.9971865, 7.8537668);
var marker_options = {
         map : map,
         icon : {  url : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png',
                   size : new google.maps.Size(32,32),
                   anchor : new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                   origin: new google.maps.Point(0,32)

         }
  };

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 //new marker object

var marker = new google.maps.Marker(marker_options);



 function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 13,
 center: freiburg,
 mapTypeId: 'terrain'
 }

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


 // Create an ElevationService
 elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();

 // Add a listener for the click event and call getElevation on that location
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', getElevation);
   }

function getElevation(event) {

 var locations = [];

 // Retrieve the clicked location and push it on the array
 var clickedLocation = event.latLng;
 locations.push(clickedLocation);

  // Create a LocationElevationRequest object using the array's one value
  var positionalRequest = {
  'locations': locations
   }

  // Initiate the location request
  elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {

  // Retrieve the first result
  if (results[0]) {

    //position Marker
    marker.setPosition(clickedLocation);

    // Open an info window indicating the elevation at the clicked position
    infowindow.setContent(Math.round(results[0].elevation) + ' m. N. N.');
    infowindow.setPosition(clickedLocation);
    infowindow.open(map);
  } else {
    alert('No results found');
  }
  } 
   else {
     alert('Elevation service failed due to: ' + status);
    }
     });
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the marker on the map, you need to set the "map" property of the [google.maps.Marker object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker):

```
   marker.setMap(map);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_elevationService.html)

[working example with custom icon definition](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_elevationService_CustomIcon.html)

Comment: You commented out the icon properties size, anchor, origin. It only works (the icon is visible) without them. Why is this?

Comment: It sort of works with them (I see a black vertical line where the marker should be).  I commented them out because they were incorrect.  If you want to use those properties you have to set them appropriately, and that wasn't the main problem, which was that you need to set the map property of the marker if you want it displayed on the map.

Comment: See [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_elevationService_CustomIcon.html)

Comment: Now I want to toggle the info-window. Therefore I put a Listener after the if-statement 'if (results[0])' Now, the info-window opens after clicking again on the marker. However, the icon reloads every time. What is wrong?

Comment: `if (results[0]) {

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
         //Marker
        marker.setPosition(clickedLocation);
        marker.setMap(map);
        // Open an info window indicating the elevation at the clicked position
        infowindow.setContent(Math.round(results[0].elevation) + ' m. N. N.');
        infowindow.setPosition(clickedLocation);
        infowindow.open(map,this);

      });

      google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');

      }`

Comment: That is a different question, see what you can do then post a question with what you have tried and what problems you are having. Please don't post lots of code in comments.  It can be formatted to be readable in a question.